# Line between two lines

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning

I'm trying to make a business card using LaTeX. This is what I have come up with so far. The only thing I'm unhappy with is that I'd like the phone number to move down half a line so that it is between the company name and  the tag line.

[image: picture of compiled latex file]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,oneside,portrait]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]{Copperplate}
\setmonofont{Monaco}
\LabelCols=2%
\LabelRows=5%
\LeftPageMargin=8.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=8.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=4mm%
\BottomPageMargin=6.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=2.0cm%
\InterLabelRow=1.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=4mm%
\RightLabelBorder=4mm%
\TopLabelBorder=0mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm%
\numberoflabels=10%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse
\newcommand{\phonenumber}{+123\textendash456\textendash789}
\newcommand{\emailaddress}{maxpower@fancywebsite.com}
\newcommand{\website}{fancywebsite.com}
%
\begin{document}
\addresslabel[\fboxsep=1mm]{%
    {\Large \phonenumber} \hfill {\LARGE CompanyName}\\   
    \hfill {\small Great Tag Line}\\
    \vspace{6ex}%
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\huge \textbf Max POWER}  
    \end{center}
    \vspace{6ex}%

    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\LARGE{\website\\ \emailaddress}}
    \end{center}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\vspace`?

Comment: `\raisebox{-4pt}{text to lower}`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the phone number and company name/tagline each in their own `tabular`, since they would necessarily be aligned vertically at the center:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,oneside,portrait]{memoir}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

\LabelCols=2%
\LabelRows=5%
\LeftPageMargin=8.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=8.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=4mm%
\BottomPageMargin=6.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=2.0cm%
\InterLabelRow=1.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=4mm%
\RightLabelBorder=4mm%
\TopLabelBorder=0mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm%
\numberoflabels=10%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse
\newcommand{\phonenumber}{+123\textendash456\textendash789}
\newcommand{\emailaddress}{maxpower@fancywebsite.com}
\newcommand{\website}{fancywebsite.com}

\begin{document}
\addresslabel[\fboxsep=1mm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
    \Large \phonenumber
  \end{tabular} \hfill 
  \begin{tabular}{r@{}}
    \LARGE CompanyName \\
    \small Great Tag Line
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{6ex}%

  \begin{center}
    \huge\scshape\bfseries Max POWER
  \end{center}

  \vspace{6ex}%

  \begin{center}
    \LARGE\scshape \website \\ \emailaddress
  \end{center}
}
\end{document}
```